# Can I only lower the volume of system prompt sound?

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. When I type command at terminal, I sometimes hit tab key unintentionally, it does not do any harm, but I get a fairly loud sound, I think it is some system prompt or alert sound.

There is nothing serious about this, just that, it is annoying.

I do not want to lower down the headphone volume though, as I am playing some music.

Is there a way I can lower the volume of such prompt sound only?

[**UPDATE**]
Thanks for the tip, the solution is to add the following to ~/.inputrc:

```
set bell-style none
```

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using (where settings are stashed varies)?  You can typically control that from the System Settings Control Center.  Try looking under Sound; see if there is a tab for system sounds.  You probably won't be able to adjust the volume for each sound, but you can typically turn specific system sounds on or off.  If there is a sound mixer (you can install one if there isn't), you can typically adjust the volume for system sounds as a whole independent of sounds from other sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very short answer:

```
$ man bash | less -p "Readline Variables"
```

The very first variable is `bell-style` - read thoroughly.

*Currently the text is this:*

> ...
>   Readline Variables
>
> Readline has variables that can be used to further customize its behavior.  A variable may be set in the inputrc file with a statement of the form
>
> set variable-name value
>
> Except  where noted, readline variables can take the values On or Off (without regard to case).  Unrecognized variable names are ignored.  When a variable value is read, empty or null values, "on" (case-insensitive), and "1" are equivalent to On.  All other values are equivalent to Off.  The variables and their default values are:
>
> bell-style (audible)
>
> Controls what happens when readline wants to ring the terminal bell.  If set to **none**, readline never rings the bell.  If set to **visible**, readline uses  a  visible  bell  if  one  is available.  If set to **audible**, readline attempts to ring the terminal's bell.

That is include ...

`set bell-style none`
or
`set bell-style visible`

... one of the files that bash 'runs' at launch. *I personally have it in the $HOME/.bash_aliases file, as $HOME/.bashrc (the other candidate) has (had?) a default file in Ubuntu.*